# Why does PHPExcel try to create a class name out of the Excel file name when used inside Kohana?

Tags: php, kohana, phpexcel

I am trying to build the **PHPExcel** library into an application built with the **Kohana** PHP framework.

In a test app **outside** the Kohana framework, I can create and read Excel files fine.

And **inside** the Kohana application, **creating** a file works:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Test Generator")
    ->setTitle("Test Excel5 File");
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Test Sheet');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('test123.xls'); //created in the root directory of application
```

However, when **inside** the Kohana framework when I try to **read a file** with this code:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('test123.xls');
```

I get this **error**:

[image]

**How can I prevent PHPExcel/Kohana from trying to create a class name out of the Excel file name?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The createReader() method expects the filetype as a parameter (eg Excel2007, Excel5, Excel2003XML, OOCalc, Gnumeric, CSV), not the filename.

```
// Use the IOFactory to instantiate a reader of the correct type
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5'); 
// Use the reader to load the file, and return a PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('test123.xls');
```